# Arduino as analog to digital converter for temperature sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, digital-analog-conversion

I have an ESP8266 module that must receive some data and send it to a server, my problem is that this data is given by a temperature sensore and a light sensor which must be connected to analog pins and my ESP has only 2 digital pins.

So I thought that I can measure the temperature and the light with an arduino (the sensors are the ones included in arduino starter pack) and then connect my esp digital pins to arduino digital pins and write a sketch to send digital data as output of arduino.

I think this is possible but I can't figure out how to do it because I can only set pins to high or low.

Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot

P.S: I already tried ther solutions like connecting tx and rx of esp to arduino but they didn't work so I prefer to use ESP8266 as standalone

Comment: Serial connection (RX/TX) seems like the way to go. If it didn't work it only means you had a bug to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Both the ESP8266 and the Arduino have UART serial interfaces. This is by far the simplest method of communicating between two boards.

Connect the TX of the Arduino, through a voltage divider to drop it to 3.3V, to the RX of the ESP8266. Connect the grounds together. That's all you need. Yes, you can connect the TX of the ESP8266 to the RX of the Arduino but if you are never going to send anything from the ESP8266 to the Arduino then there is little point.

Then, with both devices set to the same baud rate, you can `Serial.print` on the Arduino, and `Serial.read` on the ESP8266. Just follow one of the many many tutorials about communicating between Arduinos using UART.